# Is Blender using my NVIDIA Graphics card to render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have been trying to find away to try to render my animation quickly enough and an acceptable quality. My question is that is there a way for me to know whether Blender is rending using my NVIDIA graphics card? because Blender has been rendering more than 48 hours for a 2-3 seconds animation that doesn't have any movements in the background and the only movement is the characters body moving one way as well as it's hands. It is also only rendering in 100 cycles so I don't think it should take that long. Here's what I've done so far to enable GPU:

[image]
I have selected user preferences and clicked on CUDA and the GeForce 610M

[image]

I clicked on device and the GPU Computer.

Comment: it is using the graphic card, but yours isn't that powerful so if you have a good processor try using it

Comment: Theres a new update available for my NVIDIA Graphics card it is called a GeForce Game Ready Driver update. Would it improve the render speed if I  update it? Also, I have a Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2450M CPU @ 2.50GHz and a 1.6 GHz Intel Core i5 for my MacBook Air.

Comment: I think the drivers optimization would be for the high end cards ( you won"t benefit ), and for the CPU you can test on your machine ( or look for benchmarks ) render like 10 frames and see using CPU then GPU and see which is faster

Comment: Alrighty, thanks for your quickly reply as this is my school assignment and it weighs 98% of my grade. Do you know anyone that could render it for me?

Comment: there are rendering farms for blender, but i don't have experience to guide you through this ,  check the guys in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm) if they can help

Comment: That particular GPU has only 48 CUDA cores. It is unlikely that it will render any faster than on CPU